# How we call someone who knows what he wants and he is focused in achieving it

Tags: synonyms, translation

I am trying to find a word which is used to describe someone, who really knows what he wants and how to achieve it, but more important - He has the idea in mind and its clearly visible that he is focused in achieving it. Purposeful is a good candidate, but maybe there is a better one?

The sentence in which this word will be used is: "You are so ..(here lays the word, which I'm looking for)..".
This should be a complement.
There is a bulgarian word, which perfectly fits and it is exactly what I'm trying to say/translate and it is: "целеустремен".

Maybe the word Tenacious

Comment: I'd say he's "zeroed in on it."

Comment: Focused, from your own question, seems to fit.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for an adjective; please help us understand why your own suggestions "focused" and "purposeful" don't suit your needs.

Comment: @MarkBeadles As I wrote in the description, I'm searching for a better word (if there is any). It is not easy for me to explain in english the bulgarian word, which I am trying to translate. The accepted answer seems to me to be close enough. The word I search, literally means:  impetuous toward target, but without meaning that the one is careless. Sorry for the bad explanation.

Comment: Asen, it would have been good to include that information (that you were seeking a translation) in your question. Otherwise, "better" is simply too subjective.

Comment: Look up the term "single-minded" and see if its meaning matches what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest **driven**. 
From [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/driven):

> (of a person) relentlessly compelled by the need to accomplish a goal;
>   very hard-working and ambitious.

Answer (score 1):

You might choose the word "***purposed***" or "***purposeful***" to describe such a person. If a stronger word is required, then perhaps "***adamant***" might work.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/purposeful

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/adamant